# How to use Expandable ListView in Recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, expandablelistadapter

So it's been a month now that I haven't solve this simple problem.

Goal:
I want to have a expandable list where parent is textView and child is a radiogroup containing 2 (for now) radios.

I had everything working but then I learned that Expandable ListView is reusing the object suggesting to use either recyclerview or viewholder. I tried viewholder but same thing happens:
If I expand group 1 and check radio position 1, un-expand group 1 and expand group 2, radio position 1 is checked. Why is this happening?

Here's the code for myClassList extends BaseExapandableListAdapter:

```
public int getGroupCount() {
    return titles.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return titles.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public List<String> getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return colorsMap.get(titles.get(groupPosition));
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String) this.getGroup(groupPosition);
    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert (layoutInflater != null);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_item_s, parent, false);
    }
    TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.titleContent);
    textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    textView.setText(title);
    return convertView;
}
class ViewHolder{
    RadioButton radioButton;
    RadioButton radioButton1;

    ViewHolder(View view){
            radioButton = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rd1);
            radioButton1 = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.rd2);
    }


}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    List<String> color = colorsMap.get(titles.get(groupPosition));
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        assert (layoutInflater != null);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_item_s, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    holder.radioButton.setText(color.get(0));
    holder.radioButton1.setText(color.get(1));

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

How do I ensure each child is its own object?

Comment: The position is possibly the greatest gift for RecyclerViews, ListViews, etc. As the views are recycled the position provided is always the same. So eg. SparseArray can be used to hold the radio of choice at any position. Then you retrieve that and use if its no null and remove the position held if its no longer in use etc. There's plenty of ways to hold what's happening at what position. Just make sure to update all holders should the list change.

Comment: I will look up SparseArryay, thanks. Also, how did people manage this problem before the RecyclerView became a thing? There must have been people that tried to implement the same thing I am trying like in 2012 or earlier?

Answer (score 0):

There are people who have already come across your problem and created solutions for them.

Take a look at [afollestad's sectioned-recyclerview](https://github.com/afollestad/sectioned-recyclerview) and also [davideas's FlexibleAdapter](https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter). They both have guides on how to use their libraries.

Comment: I want to avoid using a lib (initially), I rather code by looking at an example which your first link provides so thank you so much for providing that.

Comment: I was like you too but other people have already been where you are and created solutions for themselves that they share. You can always edited it and tailor it to your needs, I highly recommend it. No need to reinvent the wheel :)

Comment: @rachna I ended up following afollestad's sectioned-recyclerview repo guide